# How to remove white space and special characters using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I have a form with an input field.
I show the value of the field on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#company').change(function(){
         $('#compname').html($('#company').val());
     });
});
```

I need to strip all white space and any special characters entered into the field. (So only alpha/numeric characters are shown and without spaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following regex `/[^A-Z0-9]/ig` to do this :

```
var company_name = $('#company').val().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "");
$('#compname').html(company_name);
```

**`[^A-Z0-9]`** : match a single character not present in the list below

**`A-Z`** : a single character in the range between A and Z (case insensitive)

**`0-9`** : a single character in the range between 0 and 9

**`g`** : modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

**`i`** : modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

**NOTE :** better to use `input` event to track user change inside an input.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#company').on('input', function(){
    var company_name = $('#company').val().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "");
    $('#compname').html(company_name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="company" placeholder='Company name'/>

<br><br>
Result : <span id="compname"></span>
```

Comment: Best Answer, how to keep one space in between words?

Comment: Hi @Mohammed, do you want to just trim the text (remove spaces at the start/end of the text) and remove the special characters ?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/40wx7rLf/1/ 
being fresher, I am wondering whether this was right or not. Multiple onchange Functions

Comment: Good job, it will be better to attach the events using **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to actually strip out any characters that were not explicitly alphanumeric `[^a-zA-Z\d]` via the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function :

```
// Clean up your name here
var name = $('#company').val().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/gi,'');
// Display your cleaned name
$('#compname').html(name);
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Stripping Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>Company</pre>
  <input id='company' />
  <hr />
  <h3 id='compname'></h3>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#company').keyup(function() {
        // Clean up your name here
        var name = $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/gi, '');
        // Display your cleaned name
        $('#compname').html(name);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Good Answer, how to keep one space in between words?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `\W` to match "non alphanumerics" and simply replace with nothing:

```
"  &&^mark & ".replace(/\W/g, "")  //mark
```